# How do I prevent Text "bounce" in SwiftUI SegmentedControl

Tags: swiftui, picker

I am having trouble with the text in SwiftUI SegmentedPicker bouncing when I tap on the various segments.

This is super basic so I am not sure what options there are for adjusting this:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var selectorIndex = 0
    @State private var numbers = ["One","Two","Three"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Numbers", selection: $selectorIndex) {
                ForEach(0 ..< numbers.count) { index in
                    Text(self.numbers[index]).tag(index)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())


            Text("Selected value is: \(numbers[selectorIndex])").padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a "feature" of the current version of the SwiftUI Picker. Some folks have written their own picker as a workaround.

Comment: I think you may need to create your custom picker

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to the Text, especially the alignment:

```
.frame(width: 222, height: 55, alignment: .leading)
```

Edit:

I'm using the following code to test the text bounce on real devices and various simulators:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var selectorIndex = 0
@State private var numbers = ["One","Two","Three"]

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Picker("Numbers", selection: $selectorIndex) {
            ForEach(0 ..< numbers.count) { index in
                Text(self.numbers[index]).tag(index)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        Text("Selected value is: \(numbers[selectorIndex])")
            .frame(width: 222, height: 55, alignment: .leading)
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: It does reduce the "bounce" especially on the middle segment, but it is still noticeable.

Comment: I'm not getting any "bounce" with my setup;  Mac 10.15.5 using xcode 11.6 beta (and 11.5), ios 13.5 iphone and iPad, mac catalyst. What system are you using?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the code I'm using. With that I cannot see any text bounce

Comment: Alas, I think we are referring to different text. Your updated code modifies the "Selected value is: One" text. While I am referring to the text inside each segment. Those are the text items I am seeing movement in.

Comment: well how about that, trust me to pick the wrong text. In that case, I bet this is how Apple want Pickers to behave, to show the selection change.

Comment: No harm done. Your intentions were good. So either Apple intends it this way or it is a bug. Hopefully WWDC will bring good news. Thanks for your efforts.